# Bootstrap - Align 2 divs vertically on responsive mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap, trying to align 2 divs vertical on responsive mode, but no luck so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>
<body>
    <div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1" ><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-11">
                <p>The estimated delivery date is provided to you as a guide only.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

On normal desktop mode, the divs are vertically aligned. But once I go to mobile mode, the second div is sitting below the first div. How can I make the 2nd div to sit next to the first div vertically?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1" >
```

The `col-xs-12` means, that on small screens, this element should fill the complete container. Use

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-1" >
```

for both containers, or one col-xs-1 and the other col-xs-11.

There are 12 columns in bootstrap and you decide, how they are filled

Answer (score 0):

Most of the boostrap over mobile devices tend to make things one below another because that is pretty much what bootstrap does in CSS/Div elements on mobile.
There are some solutions over it, but I see in your  elements before

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1" ><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
```

that you don't use the triple rule.
Using bootstrap col- elements should be always into container and row like this:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- Or container-fluid -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
            most inner div
        <div/>
    <div/>
<div/>
```

A little harder as solution is to copy the whole Bootstrap grid css file into a new file you make and you modify the things you need the most, like the .col-lg xs or the flex and the max width

Last but not least, go check the @media element over here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

This could help you understand the most of what I said before about auto-resizing over mobile devices and css elements

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <!--Try this one, It's simple and responsive in all widths and are aligned  vertically can also do this using css flex box but little bit lengthy.-->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <img src=" https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hF_LjTUvP-U/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="firstImg" class="img-fluid" style="width: 150px;
                height: 150px;">
        <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2554641.jpg" alt="secondImg" class="img-fluid mt-2" style="width: 150px;
                height: 150px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**strong text**